# my .js.erb file is not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my rails application I am trying to access pagination via an ajax call. I am triggering a script via index.js.erb file. The control doesn't go to that file. Please help

My controller:

```
def index
   ics_per_page=params[:ics_per_page]||5
   ics_per_page=ics_per_page.to_i
    @ics = Ic.search(params[:root_name],params[:suite_name],params[:case_name],params[:name],'f').paginate(:per_page =>ics_per_page, :page => params[:all_ics])
      respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @ics }
    end
  end
```

My index.js.erb file:

```
console.log("inside index.js.erb");
$('#listing').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("listing")) %>');
```

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: sure.could you please let me know fow to get it in firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you check again. I think the file index.js.erb is rendered but the content is not executed because of a wrong content type. set the content type to specify that it is javascript.

```
format.js { render :content_type => 'text/javascript' }
```

Comment: Hi Alok, What I am able to find out is even if i don't have index.js.erb in the directory its not throwing an error.Ideally ir should throw an error rt?

Comment: what is the output on Rails log ? Is the call to index action an XHR ?

Comment: Hi Alok after commenting out console.log and giving an alert msg I am getting the Rendered ics/_listing.html.haml (185.0ms)
Rendered ics/index.js.erb (191.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 321ms (Views: 225.9ms | ActiveRecord: 14.7ms)
But the page output is displayed with html tags. i.e the basic html format

Comment: how are you calling the index action ?

Comment: index action is called on loading the page

Comment: I think you have to call the action through a XML HTTP Request so that the mime type is set to text/javascript.